# List yahoo/hotmail email domains

Tags: email, mx-record

Problem:

I want to get/find a list of yahoo owned domain names that would, given the same local part, go to the same mailbox. And analogously, a list of such hotmail domains.

Background:

I have an application where, as a matter of policy, users are allowed to only have one account, and violation of that rule is detected by, among other things, email address uniqueness.

I'd like to normalize email addresses, in order to detect syntactically obvious duplicates. I'm aware that the normalizaton process won't cover all emails a person can use (case in point - G-Suite will have gmail rules, but that can't be known from syntax alone; one would have to check MX records), but still, I'd like to cover as much ground as possible with the string alone... I already lowercase, detect plus addressing, or in Yahoo's case, hyphen addressing, and in the case of gmail, I remove the dots, all in order to get a normalized local part.

Yahoo and Hotmail/Live/Outlook however is giving me trouble with their domains... An email that ends with "yahoo.com" or "yahoo.co.uk" will both lead to the same mailbox, meaning one should be normalized to the other. So far, so good, except that there are a lot of other such domains.

I tried looking at their SSL certificate, but the list of domains there was incomplete. I found two country extensions that weren't in it (they still led to the same web server with an SSL error), and I was able to login with them. I expect there are more.

Similarly, I'm not entirely sure about Microsoft owned sites like hotmail.com variants, live.com variants, and outlook.com variants.

So, is there anywhere a list of such domains? Any way to reliably generate such domains?

Comment: this is not possible. due the fact i can own a domain and mailserver, aslong in willed to write new alias aslong i will be able to join multiple times. i would do this more on a webbased fact i. e. cookie, ip Session id from same ip etc

Comment: Like I said, I'm aware this won't cover all cases. The goal of this heuristic isn't to prevent registrations (as there's no technical reason not to allow it), but to alert staff of its possible policy violation.

The app will also track source IP and session in addition to the email as another such "this may be a violation of the policy" signal.